# MySql Модель таблиц и Внешние ключи Для сообщний между пользователями

Tags: mysql, база-данных, архитектура

На сайте реализуется возможность обмена сообщениями между пользователями
у каждого пользователя есть возможность отправлять и получать сообщения, раскладывать сообщения по разделам. Для этого реализованы две таблицы, с сообщениями: 
[image: Таблица с сообщениями, связь с таблицей секций через section_id]

И таблица с разделами(секциями):
[image: Таблица с разделами]

Далее возникает проблема: допустим отправитель создаёт в разделе Исходящие подраздел, и кладёт туда сообщение в БД оно соответствующим образом сохраняется, Когда получатель сообщения загружает раздел своих сообщений, то сообщения в разделах у него уже не будут отображаться (таблица с сообщениями сортируется по резделам пользователя).
Таким образом необходимо создать id для секции отправителя и id для секций получателя и связать их с id таблицы разделов:
[image: Таблица сообщений для хранения id секций получателя и отправителя]

Но здесь возникает проблема: при попытке привязать sen_sec_id и rec_sec_id с id из таблицы с разделами, возникает ошибка "Error 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails"

Подскажите пожалуйста можно ли сделать такую связь, либо всё-таки лучше разделить таблицу с разделами на разделы отправителей и разделы получателей?

Не совсем понятно почему это не возможно, ведь каждое значение id раздела уникально.

Comment: Вообще-то должна существовать таблица, которая связывает пользователя, раздел и сообщение. Разделы-то у каждого свои, небось? А отсутствие записи в этой таблице. вероятно, отправляет сообщение в "Непрочитанные".

Comment: *Не совсем понятно почему это не возможно* на скриншоте же русским по белому нули в `rec_sec_id` - у тебя есть раздел с таким `id`? нету. Во-о-от... PS. NULL вместо нуля мог бы помочь...